# What could explain radically different HRs and ORs with similar absolute probabilities

Tags: probability, clinical-trials, proportional-hazards

This is a weird question that may not have a good answer, but I thought I'd take a shot.

In this clinical trial (hereafter, the ACTT-I Trial: https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2007764), it was found that in "severe patients" 7.6% in the treatment group died at Day 14 compared to 13% in placebo at Day 14.

Here is the data which proves this (the first link I sent only has the data for overall, not the severe subgroup):
https://www.nejm.org/doi/suppl/10.1056/NEJMoa2007764/suppl_file/nejmoa2007764_appendix.pdf (on Page 23).

This corresponded to a Hazard Ratio (Stratified Cox) of 0.71 (favoring treatment).

However, the same company then announced something else today (link: https://www.gilead.com/news-and-press/press-room/press-releases/2020/7/gilead-presents-additional-data-on-investigational-antiviral-remdesivir-for-the-treatment-of-covid-19).

In a retrospective analysis comparing a subset of "severe" patients from the SIMPLE trial (a separate trial from the ACTT-I trial mentioned above) to a set of historical controls, they found very similar overall probabilities of death: 7.6% at  Day 14 compared with 12.5% in the SoC group at Day 14.

However, they go on to say, that this corresponded to an adjusted odds ratio 0.38, 95% confidence interval 0.22-0.68, p=0.001).

One analysis used HRs and the other ORs, and of course, the trials themselves are not completely comparable. The second analysis was a *retrospective* study and because it's just a press release we cannot guarantee that the patient populations that they label as "severe" were the same in both trials (for example, in the ACTT-1 trial, severe has a precise definition, whereas in SIMPLE the definition is not publically stated so far). But assuming that they were, what *could* be the explanation for such differing assessments of the reduction in the risk of mortality, ~30% for one trial, ~60% for the other?

Comment: [Every hazard ratio has selection bias built into itself](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmc3653612/).

Comment: Was the HR adjusted for anything? It seems the OR was adjusted, which may explain some difference given the retrospective nature.